# jquery tabs - show next tab after selection

Tags: jquery, tabs

If I have 4 tab, 1st shows by default obvioiusly..

In Tab 1, there will be 2 links (or more).

Tab 2 is only accessible once a selection has been made in Tab 1.

Same goes for Tab 3, and Tab 4.

Lastly, if I selected a item in Tab 1, and now I am on Tab 2, I'd like to be able to see Tab 1's selection outside of the element.

Little tricky, but I'm even willing to paypal some $ for this one :)

Also, if a jquery progress bar can be incorporated that would be great!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code for hire site.

Comment: +1 @Andrew / And have you actually tried to build something like this yourself yet? It's not all that bad. And if you hit a wall, you can always come back and ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the jQuery Form Wizard plugin?

http://thecodemine.org/

Comment: This does not answer the question. The codemine is a form wizard not a tab management system which seems to be what dave is looking for.

Comment: This may actually work! I'll give it a try & update this page

Comment: Yes thank you!  Still working out certain issues but for the most part working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
it's easy and fast to implement.